# How would I print more blocks horizontally?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void TimesTable(int count)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++)
    {
        cout << count << " x " << j << " = " << count*j << " " << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (int count = 1; count < 13; count++)
    {
        TimesTable(count);
        cout << endl;
    }

        system("Pause");
}
```

This prints

```
"1 x 1 = 1
 1 x 2 = 2

 2x1 = 2
 2x2 = 4

 3x1 = 3
 3x2 = 6"
```

and so on. But the thing I want to do is so instead of having them all print in a line downwards, I want to have it in blocks so,

```
 "1 x 1 = 1   2 x 1 = 2   3 x 1  = 3  4 x  1 = 4  5 x 1  = 5
  1 x 2  = 2  2 x 2 = 4   3 x 2 = 6   4 x 2 = 8   5 x 2 = 10"
```

and so on. But obviously it would look better if it didn't then go to 12 horizontally or otherwise you'd have to grab the bar at the bottom of the console window and drag to see the other timestables. I'd like it so that it went to 5 on block line 1 then on the 2nd line of blocks it would be 6 to 10 and the final line 10 to 12.

Yes it's random that it only goes up to 12 but it was an exercise and I've just adapted it into some other monster.

And I guess I could just have more than one cout in the for loop but I swear in the past I've seen someone do this with just a clever way of passing through a variable so that it printed a block of asterisks side by side instead of pretending to do it.

Desired Result (make it easier with symbols instead):

```
" ***** ^^^^^ &&&&&
  ***** ^^^^^ &&&&&
  ***** ^^^^^ &&&&& "
```

Result as of now:

```
" *****
  *****
  *****

  ^^^^^
  ^^^^^
  ^^^^^

  &&&&&
  &&&&&
  &&&&& "
```

Answer (score 2):

To format columns, use [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) from `<iomanip>`

> Sets the field width to be used on output operations.

now.

outside, iterate over the lines.

inside, iterate over the columns.

### CODE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int cols_per_line = 5;
    for (int line = 1; line < 13; line++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= cols_per_line; col++)
        {
            cout << setw(2) << col << " x " << setw(2) << line << " = " << setw(3) << line*col << "   ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

### OUTPUT

```
[root@rnrlabs ~]# ./a.out
 1 x  1 =   1    2 x  1 =   2    3 x  1 =   3    4 x  1 =   4    5 x  1 =   5
 1 x  2 =   2    2 x  2 =   4    3 x  2 =   6    4 x  2 =   8    5 x  2 =  10
 1 x  3 =   3    2 x  3 =   6    3 x  3 =   9    4 x  3 =  12    5 x  3 =  15
 1 x  4 =   4    2 x  4 =   8    3 x  4 =  12    4 x  4 =  16    5 x  4 =  20
 1 x  5 =   5    2 x  5 =  10    3 x  5 =  15    4 x  5 =  20    5 x  5 =  25
 1 x  6 =   6    2 x  6 =  12    3 x  6 =  18    4 x  6 =  24    5 x  6 =  30
 1 x  7 =   7    2 x  7 =  14    3 x  7 =  21    4 x  7 =  28    5 x  7 =  35
 1 x  8 =   8    2 x  8 =  16    3 x  8 =  24    4 x  8 =  32    5 x  8 =  40
 1 x  9 =   9    2 x  9 =  18    3 x  9 =  27    4 x  9 =  36    5 x  9 =  45
 1 x 10 =  10    2 x 10 =  20    3 x 10 =  30    4 x 10 =  40    5 x 10 =  50
 1 x 11 =  11    2 x 11 =  22    3 x 11 =  33    4 x 11 =  44    5 x 11 =  55
 1 x 12 =  12    2 x 12 =  24    3 x 12 =  36    4 x 12 =  48    5 x 12 =  60
```

Comment: No, different timestables in different columns. First line: 5 different columns of timetables.

Comment: sorry my explanation must've been pretty hard to follow but. 1x1, 1x2, 1x3 all go in one column. then right of it on the console... 2x1, 2x2, 2x3 all go in one column and so on. so each row has 5 columns of different timestables on it.

Comment: i got it (i think) :P

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the endl at the end of TimeTable for inner "for"
and add another counter for splitter say:

Edit: change j with count.

```
 int splitter = 0;
 for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++, splitter++)
 {
    cout << j << " x " << count  << " = " << count*j << "\t";
    if (splitter == 5)
    {
       cout << endl;
       splitter=-1;
    }
 }


1 x 1 = 1   2 x 1 = 2   3 x 1 = 3   4 x 1 = 4   5 x 1 = 5   6 x 1 = 6   
7 x 1 = 7   8 x 1 = 8   9 x 1 = 9   10 x 1 = 10 11 x 1 = 11 12 x 1 = 12 

1 x 2 = 2   2 x 2 = 4   3 x 2 = 6   4 x 2 = 8   5 x 2 = 10  6 x 2 = 12  
7 x 2 = 14  8 x 2 = 16  9 x 2 = 18  10 x 2 = 20 11 x 2 = 22 12 x 2 = 24 

1 x 3 = 3   2 x 3 = 6   3 x 3 = 9   4 x 3 = 12  5 x 3 = 15  6 x 3 = 18  
7 x 3 = 21  8 x 3 = 24  9 x 3 = 27  10 x 3 = 30 11 x 3 = 33 12 x 3 = 36 

1 x 4 = 4   2 x 4 = 8   3 x 4 = 12  4 x 4 = 16  5 x 4 = 20  6 x 4 = 24  
7 x 4 = 28  8 x 4 = 32  9 x 4 = 36  10 x 4 = 40 11 x 4 = 44 12 x 4 = 48 

1 x 5 = 5   2 x 5 = 10  3 x 5 = 15  4 x 5 = 20  5 x 5 = 25  6 x 5 = 30  
7 x 5 = 35  8 x 5 = 40  9 x 5 = 45  10 x 5 = 50 11 x 5 = 55 12 x 5 = 60 

1 x 6 = 6   2 x 6 = 12  3 x 6 = 18  4 x 6 = 24  5 x 6 = 30  6 x 6 = 36  
7 x 6 = 42  8 x 6 = 48  9 x 6 = 54  10 x 6 = 60 11 x 6 = 66 12 x 6 = 72 

1 x 7 = 7   2 x 7 = 14  3 x 7 = 21  4 x 7 = 28  5 x 7 = 35  6 x 7 = 42  
7 x 7 = 49  8 x 7 = 56  9 x 7 = 63  10 x 7 = 70 11 x 7 = 77 12 x 7 = 84 

1 x 8 = 8   2 x 8 = 16  3 x 8 = 24  4 x 8 = 32  5 x 8 = 40  6 x 8 = 48  
7 x 8 = 56  8 x 8 = 64  9 x 8 = 72  10 x 8 = 80 11 x 8 = 88 12 x 8 = 96 

1 x 9 = 9   2 x 9 = 18  3 x 9 = 27  4 x 9 = 36  5 x 9 = 45  6 x 9 = 54  
7 x 9 = 63  8 x 9 = 72  9 x 9 = 81  10 x 9 = 90 11 x 9 = 99 12 x 9 = 108    

1 x 10 = 10 2 x 10 = 20 3 x 10 = 30 4 x 10 = 40 5 x 10 = 50 6 x 10 = 60 
7 x 10 = 70 8 x 10 = 80 9 x 10 = 90 10 x 10 = 100   11 x 10 = 110   12 x 10 = 120   

1 x 11 = 11 2 x 11 = 22 3 x 11 = 33 4 x 11 = 44 5 x 11 = 55 6 x 11 = 66 
7 x 11 = 77 8 x 11 = 88 9 x 11 = 99 10 x 11 = 110   11 x 11 = 121   12 x 11 = 132   

1 x 12 = 12 2 x 12 = 24 3 x 12 = 36 4 x 12 = 48 5 x 12 = 60 6 x 12 = 72 
7 x 12 = 84 8 x 12 = 96 9 x 12 = 108    10 x 12 = 120   11 x 12 = 132   12 x 12 = 144
```

Comment: No sorry it was hard to explain but I want it to be specifically in columns side by side to each other.

Comment: for have a column you can insert an \t after each row

Comment: No I know how to get columns I already have that working. I just need to know how to do one set of columns then another set of columns by the side. Right now it goes "1x1 =1 2x1 =2  then below it 2x1= 2 2x2 = "

Comment: could you just write or draw what is the result you want? :)

Comment: Ok look at the original post formatting is easier in that.

Comment: I think my code will show this as you want, I don't have environment to check it, please check it, and show the result to correct it if any problem exist

Comment: Good effort but it does blocks of the same timestable next to them... so it goes " *** *** *** " but it needs to be different blocks... A block would be the 1x table eg. "****" then the 2x table which is normally vertically below it would be on its right, "***** ^^^^" ^ = stands for the 2x table. But it can't be ALL of the timestable on one line, I want them seperated as normal on different lines next to each other.